# Why inner function call from html Run first than the parent function call Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have two functions, the first one is myFunction() and myDiv()

```
<div (click)="myDiv()">
   <button (click)="myFunction()"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

In AppComponent I have the defination of both functions like this:

```
myFunction()
{
  console.log("I am in myFunction");
}

myDiv()
{
  console.log("I am in myDiv");
}
```

**The output of this will be:**

I am in myFunction

I am in myDiv

Why myFunction run first before myDiv? What is the reason?

Comment: The reason is the this is how events propagate. Read about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `click` event is bubbling

```
<html>(document)                                              
                                                       /\
  <div (click)="myDiv()">                              || 

                                                       /\
     <button (click)="myFunction()"> Submit </button>  ||
  </div>
```

See also

- https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

If you want to `myDiv` handler be called first you should catch event in the **capturing** phase

```
el.addEventListener('click', myDiv, true); 
                                     \/
                                  useCapture
```

AFAIK angular doesn't support `useCapture` option. Here is a **[workaround](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjgnim?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: I don't understand how can i add useCapture in my code
I have added ElementRef and renderer

Comment: I've added example to my answer

Comment: I am getting this error after modifying my code:
Cannot read property of nativeElement of undefined is null

Comment: after putting code in ngAfterViewInit() it works, i have a question why it is not working in ngOnInit()

Comment: Seems your div inside ng-template and you have to wait till ngAfterViewInit